# Dynamic checkboxes - check by a onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Say I have some checkboxes like below:

```
<label class="ck-button" id="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="form-field-checkbox" class="ace chkb">
    <span class="lbl txt" >1</span>japan      
</label>
<label class="ck-button" id="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="form-field-checkbox" class="ace chkb">
    <span class="lbl txt" >2</span>Uk  
</label>
<label class="ck-button" id="3"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="form-field-checkbox" class="ace chkb">        
    <span class="lbl txt" >3</span>USA     
</label>
```

Since I have special usage of this checkbox I have a function to prevent it's default action and use `prop()` to check it. I am using `$(this)` here is because I have lot of similar buttons.

```
$(".ck-button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).find(".ace .chkb").prop('checked', true);
});
```

I thought `find()` allows me to get access to the checkbox and check it but it doesn't work, why?

Comment: `$(this).find(".ace.chkb").prop('checked', true);` `.ace.chkb` no space if you put space meaning `.ace` is parent of `.chkb`

Comment: `.find(".ace .chkb")` selector is wrong, it should be `.find(".ace.chkb")` but anyway you could just use the default behaviour, don't you?

Comment: Use the `change` event, not `click`, when dealing with checkboxes.

Comment: the click happens on the label @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @guradio So it does. The point remains though, use the `change` on the checkbox, not the `click` of the label. It's for accessibility reasons

Comment: i got to use css to make it alike a button therefore i can't actually use the default behavior. –

Comment: @anson920520 Wouldn't have you better to use radio button(s) instead?

Comment: it needs to be mult-select able

Comment: checkbox can be multi selectable only radio button with same name is not multiple selectable